# Finding a material transparent to 26GHz radio waves for radome protecting a radar rangefinder probe

Tags: radar, damping-factor

I want to use a 26GHz radar probe to measure water levels for some outdoors applications. These are pretty common devices, one manufacturer among many others is for example:

https://en.supmea.com/cpdetail_28_297_307.html

My use is a bit specific as the sensor may be subject to very harsh conditions, so I want to harden it quite a bit. We will build a robust box around the whole head of the sensors including the divergent.

The only problem is to know which material to use to close the protection box "from below", i.e. where the radar signal propagates, i.e. which material to use at the exit of the divergent (our "radome"). This protection is necessary as there may be saltwater coming with quite high velocity / pressure from below the sensor, and while the sensor is IP67, this may not be enough to ensure durability in my use case.

So what I am looking for really is a material that is reasonably strong mechanically, that I can get my hands on, and that will be reasonably transparent to 26GHz radar waves. Any suggestions? Any kind of plastics or other that could fit the needs?

PS: If this is the wrong place to ask this question, sorry in advance and let me know, I can move the question.

Comment: depending on the scale of things, we call these covers for antennas "radomes"

Comment: Agree :) Though somehow I (probably wrongly) think about radomes as having a round shape ^^ . But I can update title etc.

Comment: Basically, it's hard to recommend anything without knowing your tolerance against absorption and diffraction.. but here we go: your sensor certainly has SNR to spare, so how about you just prototype with a normal ABS electrical installation box.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the difficulty is that I cannot easily get this data from the manufacturer either, guess it is a trade secret... As a consequence, I am looking more or less for the "best possible materials that are reasonably affordable". The idea was as you say to have a test campaign in the lab :) So you think ABS should be good? Are there other plastics that may be good candidates?

Comment: As said, without understanding your application in way more detail, it's all a guessing game, and ABS being the standard "put something in a box against the elements" material" is a natural choice. We don't know how much you need to care about RF properties of your material, so I'd simply go with it – this is trial&error, no matter what we do, so start cheap and easy.

Comment: Since it's a rangefinder can you not set up a jig to hold potential sample materials in front of the bare unit prior to making up a box.

Comment: Given your environment I'd try glass weave and marine epoxy. It's cheap and available. If its loss is more than you want, move to the quartz alternative in Tom's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Any dielectric**

A dielectric slab has a reflection from both faces, which interact and can cancel the transmitted wave. One way to manage this is to keep the radome very thin (see below), perhaps less than 1/10 wavelength.

The other way is that a dielectric will transmit the wave effectively if the slab is *half a wavelength thick*. There will still be losses in the material itself, but the reflection loss will be minimum there.

This is a diagram I found of the transmission through a slab([Rutgers](https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/ewa/ch05.pdf)):
[image]

At 26 GHz, half a wavelength is [5.8 mm](https://www.google.com/search?q=0.5%20*%20%28speed%20of%20light%29%20%2F%20%2826%20GHz%29) in free space. In the dielectric light is is slower by the square root of the relative permittivity of the medium.  For a common low-loss plastic like polypropylene or polyethylene, with Er of 2.3, the half-wave thickness is 2.3 mm. So a 2.3 mm thick radome should provide minimum loss (and a 1.2 mm radome provides maximum loss)

**2. Quartz.**
A strong, transparent radome for 26 GHz can be made of quartz glass (quartz fibres in epoxy) less than 1 mm thick. Quartz has a lower dielectric constant than glass, and lower loss. It's also more expensive and harder to buy.

If this isn't strong enough for your application, a sandwich of (say) 0.5 mm quartz, 2.5 mm engineering foam and quartz again.

For a single patch antenna or a small group of them, the radome won't need to be very big. You might make up a front panel that's say 3 mm glass fibre for most of the panel, and then switch to 0.5 mm quartz just for the window in front of the antenna. Trial and error using a sheet of aluminum foil with a hole in it, to find the required window size.

Comment: So probably something in this kind would be a good first try, right? :) https://sinoptix.fr/showroom/quartz-cells/

Comment: Interesting, that would work but it will be very expensive and hard to interface to your enclosure. Also not sure you'll get 1 mm optical quartz. And it won't be so resilient. I'm thinking of a composite - quartz fibres with epoxy resin, laid up by hand and vacuum bagged.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the details :)

Comment: @tomnexus carbon fibres? That sounds like it'd have a very tangible (huh, a pun) \$\tan \delta\$?

Comment: @marcus yes it's pretty conductive, could be modelled as metal for reflection/transmission purposes, though too lossy as an antenna conductor. Its just cheaper and stronger than the quartz. Regular glass would also work, the main thing is to have only a small window, keep the rest strong and heavy.